# Is it possible to install application while creating Azure VM from PowerShell?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to create a new Azure VM from PowerShell.

I am currently using the below script to create VM:

```
$location = "EastUS"

$rgName = "TestRG"

$credential = Get-Credential

New-AzResourceGroup -Name $rgName -Location $location

New-AzVm `
    -ResourceGroupName $rgName `
    -Name "TestVM" `
    -Location $location `
    -VirtualNetworkName "TestVnet" `
    -SubnetName "TestSubnet" `
    -SecurityGroupName "TestNsg" `
    -PublicIpAddressName "TestPip" `
    -OpenPorts 80,3389 `
    -Credential $credential
```

Can anyone achieve installing applications from PowerShell into Azure VM while creating it? If it's possible, how to do that? Can anyone assist??

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can not install apllication or add extension to the VM while creating the VM . Once VM will be provisioned then only can only install the application or the add the extension.

You can refer this [***Micorosoft Document***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-automate-vm-deployment) to install the Custom Script Extension Using `Set-AzVMExtension`.